# The Messages app doesn't recognise numbers that are saved in Contacts app

Tags: messages, contacts

I am using Contacts OSX and iOS app's and they both synced into iCloud and I have opened them to check if the contacts are the same on my phone and Mac and they are.

However when I receive an iMessage or Text message in Messages OSX it doesn't recognise the number even though that number is saved in Contacts.

Comment: Go to System Preferences → iCloud and toggle the checkmark besides Contacts to uncheck and check. This will trigger re-sync of contacts in the Contacts app. See if that helps.